# How can I view/export/determine the configuration of a Windows ADCS CA?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, pki

I'm in the process of setting up a new root ADCS (Active Directory Certificate Server) certificate authority for a child domain in a multi-forest environment that already has a number of existing CAs.  I would very much like to not repeat what the last guy did, which was to set stuff up in an ad hoc fashion and document nothing, so I'm looking for a way to standardize the configuration of our CAs.

To that end, is there a way to view/export/determine the configuration of a Windows ADCS CA?  In particular, the settings I can't seem to determine are the `Private Key Cryptography options`, as in the below setup dialogue.

[image]

The existing CAs are Server 2008 R2 or Server 2012 R2, so ideally/hopefully, I'm looking for a solution that works for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go see if you can snag the `CAPolicy.inf` file from the Windows directory on one of the existing CAs. It should still be there.

Other than that, it's all in the registry of the CA:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\My-CA`

[image: CA Registry]

Edit: I misread "**not** repeat what the last guy did"

Answer (score 2):

I think you can extract pretty much any data from your PKI with these powershell extensions - not 100% sure on your exact query but i don't see why not.

https://pspki.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks promising, thanks... I'm installing and trying that now.

Comment: Well, it leaves a lot to be desired, so I'm gonna try to find something better, but thank you... it *almost* does everything I need.  It's missing one of the settings I need, and reports a couple of the others by their reference (`System.Security.Cryptography.Oid`) instead of the actual value... d'oh.